# can not share video to facebook using open graph API

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using following meta tags but i am not receiving the video share, it only gives the url of website.

You can test the results in facebook sharing Debuuger by using this ;link
`https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/masjid.php?var_id=42`
I am using following code:

```
$readingData = $obj->read_specific("name,address,description,prof_pic,city_postcode,videoName","reg","id = '".$_GET['var_id']."'");
    $mosqueInfo = $readingMosque->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $readingData ['name'];
    $pic = $readingData ['prof_pic'];
    $description = $readingData ['description'];
    $add = $readingData ['address']; 
$postcode=$readingData ['city_postcode'];
    $video = $readingData ['videoName'];
    ?>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="258374655358948" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo $description ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/mosque/portal/images/mosques/<?php echo $pic; ?>" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo $name; ?>, Address: <?php echo $add; ?> , POST CODE: <?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <link property="og:url"           content="https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/video.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['var_id'] ?>"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/videos.php?id=<?php echo $video ?>">

<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Global Muslim"/>
```

Comment: You specified `og:video` as `https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/videos.php?id=template.mp4`, but that URL does not even deliver a video, it returns an HTML document.

Comment: And just FYI, even if you do everything right, Facebook will likely not play your video inline in newsfeed any more anyway. Most of the time, clicking on the thumbnail will just take people to your site, so that they can watch the video there. Guess the motivation behind that was to push people towards using Facebook’s own video functionality.

Comment: CBroe what should i do to return a video ??

Comment: Put the URL to an actual .mp4 file.

Comment: i added the URL of video but its still showing image, url,description and title, but not showing video. I have read on some posts that we need our own media player for sharing videos to facebook using open graph API, can you share me any example of working code ??

Comment: _“but not showing video”_ - that was to be expected, see my second comment. _“I have read on some posts that we need our own media player”_ - that must have been really old stuff, referring to Flash.

Comment: can you refer me any example the one you mentioned in comment, i only want to display the video on facebook, if user clicks it then he should be directed to my web page

Comment: You can not display “only the video”, Facebook will show the thumbnail, title and description, like with any other link post.